# COMException occurred in IConnectionPoint Unadvise()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, interop, comexception

I'm developing a program that checks if the Windows Form application is connected to the internet or not.

I based my code from the following link:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34650/How-to-use-the-Windows-NLM-API-to-get-notified-of

I'm getting this **System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException** in the **Unadvise()** method of class **IConnectionPoint** and I'm not sure as to why.

Here is the additional information of the exception:

> There is no connection for this connection ID (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040004 (OLE_E_NOCONNECTION))

Here is the method where **Advise()** is called:

```
private INetworkListManager nlm;
private IConnectionPoint icp;
private int cookie = 0;

public void AdviseNetworkListManager()
{
    try
    {
        IConnectionPointContainer icpc = (IConnectionPointContainer)nlm;
        Guid guid = typeof(INetworkListManagerEvents).GUID;
        icpc.FindConnectionPoint(ref guid, out icp);
        icp.Advise(this, out cookie);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

And here is the method where **Unadvise()** is called:

```
public void UnadviseNetworkListManager()
{
    icp.Unadvise(cookie);
}
```

And here is the constructor and event that calls both the above methods:

```
private NetworkHelper netHelper;

public SQLiteForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SQLiteDatabase.ConnectDB();
    DBHelper.ConnectDB();
    netHelper = new NetworkHelper();
    netHelper.AdviseNetworkListManager();
    netHelper.DoBackgroundWork += backgroundWorker_DoWork;
}

private void SQLiteForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    netHelper.UnadviseNetworkListManager();
    DBHelper.DisconnectDB();
    SQLiteDatabase.DisconnectDB();
    Application.Exit();
}
```

Does anyone know as to why I'm getting this exception?

Comment: Typical Codeproject.com junk without the "only works on my machine" disclaimer.,  Just do this the correct way, use += to subscribe events.  So nlm.NetworkConnectivityChanged += YourMethod;

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a **NetworkConnectivityChanged** delegate for the **INetworkListManager** class. What I did was implement the **INetworkListManagerEvents** to the class containing the Advise() and Unadvise() and implemented the **ConnectivityChanged()** within the class. Will that cause any issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what's the problem now!

Upon debugging, I've noticed that when **Application.Exit()** is executed, it calls the **SQLiteForm_FormClosing** event again. Since the **Unadvise()** is already executed, it throws the OLE_E_NOCONNECTION exception.

I have solved this by moving the **Application.Exit()** to the **SQLiteForm_FormClosed** event as such:

```
private void SQLiteForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Exit();
}
```

That way it won't call the **SQLiteForm_FormClosing** event anymore since the form is already closed.